# Error in mean of finite set of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

If I have a finite sample of $N$ values $X_i$, where $X_i$ is a random variable drawn from a uniform, continuous distribution on $[0,1]$, is there a way to estimate the error of the mean value as a function of N?  Specifically, in the limit $N \rightarrow\infty$, the expected value $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X] = 1/2$, while for finite $N$, the mean is $\langle X\rangle = (1/N)\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$, and the error I want to compute is err $=\sqrt{(\langle X\rangle -\mu)^2}$.

Comment: I think your formulas for expected values and variances are not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

For $U_i \stackrel{indep}{\sim} \mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ we have $\mu =E(U_i) = 1/2,$ and $\sigma^2 =Var(U_i) = 1/12.$

Then let $\bar X = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n U_i,$
for which $E(\bar X) = \mu = 1/2,\,$ $Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/n =1/12n,$ and
$SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n} = 1/\sqrt{12n}.$

Simulation with 100,000 $\bar X$s for samples of size $n=10,$ denoted `a` in the
R code. With 100,000 replications one can expect about two or 3 places of accuracy.

```
set.seed(916)
a = replicate(10^5, mean(runif(10)))
mean(a)
[1] 0.5000505   # aprx 1/2
sd(a)
[1] 0.09115773  # aprx 0.09129
1/sqrt(120)
[1] 0.09128709
```

Furthermore, for $n$ as large as $10,$ the mean of $n$ standard uniform random variables is approximately normal.

```
hist(a, prob=T, ylim=c(0,4.5), col="skyblue2", 
     main="UNIF(0,1): Approx. Norm Dist'n of Means of 10")
 curve(dnorm(x, 1/2, 1/sqrt(120)), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]